# R Keltner Channels

Tags: r, quantmod

Is there any package for R that already implements Keltner Channels, what I'm trying to find out is in which channel the daily close price is positioned (-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3)

I found the ATR function in TTR but I'm not sure if there is a way to use it, what I'm trying to get is something similar to what the link describes, I only need the values, not the graph, so that I can compare the daily closing price vs the channels

[Keltner Channels : StockCharts.com](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:keltner_channels)

[Keltner Channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze8Bi.png)

Any help pointing me on the right direction is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of template code will help you get what you specifically want.  Choose your own n values etc.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")

get_Keltner_channels <- function(ohlc, n_EMA = 10, n_ATR = 14, multiplier = 2) {
    mid <- EMA(Cl(ohlc), n_EMA)    
    hi <- mid + multiplier * ATR(HLC = HLC(ohlc), n = n_ATR)$atr
    lo <- mid - multiplier * ATR(HLC = HLC(ohlc), n = n_ATR)$atr
    keltner <- cbind(lo, mid, hi)
    colnames(keltner) <- c("Kelt_lo", "Kelt_mid", "Kelt_hi")
    keltner
}

out <- get_Keltner_channels(AAPL)

# > tail(out)
# Kelt_lo Kelt_mid   Kelt_hi
# 2016-07-15 94.26621 97.09092  99.91563
# 2016-07-18 94.74742 97.58893 100.43045
# 2016-07-19 95.27084 98.00367 100.73651
# 2016-07-20 95.71888 98.35937 100.99986
# 2016-07-21 95.83500 98.55403 101.27306
# 2016-07-22 95.88848 98.57330 101.25811
```

Comment: `Reduce(merge, list(lo, mid, hi))` is unnecessary.  Use the TTR functions as a template, and use the `try.xts`/`reclass` paradigm. Then you can replace the `Reduce` line with `keltner <- cbind(lo, mid, hi)`.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich  Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

```
KC <- function(x, n.ema = 20, n.atr = 10, multiplier = 2, maType='EMA') {
    x <- try.xts(x, error = as.matrix)
    ma <- do.call(what = maType, args = list(Cl(x), n.ema))
    atr <- ATR(HLC(x), n = n.atr, maType = maType)$atr
    upper <- ma + multiplier * atr
    lower <- ma - multiplier * atr
    r <- cbind(lower, ma, upper)
    colnames(r) <- c("KC.lower", "KC.mid", "KC.upper")
    return(reclass(r,x))
}

addKC <- newTA(FUN = KC, on = -1, col = rep('cornflowerblue', 3), lty = rep('dotted', 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like dplyr, this might be of help.  Season to taste.

```
keltnerEmaPeriods = 20
keltnerAtrPeriods = 20
keltnerAtrMultiplier = 1.5
      
tidyquant::tq_mutate( mutate_fun=EMA, select=close, n=keltnerEmaPeriods) %>%
dplyr::rename( "Keltner_average"="EMA" ) %>%
tidyquant::tq_mutate( mutate_fun=ATR, n=keltnerAtrPeriods ) %>%
dplyr::select( -c("tr", "ATR", "ATR..1") ) %>%
dplyr::mutate( "Keltner_lower" = Keltner_average - keltnerAtrMultiplier * atr) %>%
dplyr::mutate( "Keltner_upper" = Keltner_average + keltnerAtrMultiplier * atr) %>%
```